# Ttitle <H1> returned in different encoding than needed when scraped through VBA

Tags: vba, web-scraping, encoding, automation

I am using the following function to scrape the title of the website through VBA, however, I struggle with the encoding of some characters (e.g. dash symbol) as these are returned as e.g. Communiqués du Conseil des Ministres **–** Présidence de la république de Côte **d&#039**;ivoire. The title I am fetching can be found here: https://www.presidence.ci/communiques-du-conseil-des-ministres/. Is there any way to fix this through alteration of the existent function?

```
Function fgetMetaTitle(ByVal strURL) As String

Dim stPnt As Long, x As String
Dim oXH As Object
'Get URL's HTML Source
Set oXH = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
With oXH
    .Open "get", strURL, False
    .send
    x = .responseText
End With
Set oXH = Nothing
'Parse HTML Source for Title
If InStr(1, UCase(x), "<TITLE>") Then
    stPnt = InStr(1, UCase(x), "<TITLE>") + Len("<TITLE>")
    fgetMetaTitle = Mid(x, stPnt, InStr(stPnt, UCase(x), "</TITLE>") - stPnt)
Else
    fgetMetaTitle = ""
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this (I added handlers for dash and apostrophe):

```
Function fgetMetaTitle(ByVal strURL) As String

Dim stPnt As Long, x As String
Dim oXH As Object
'Get URL's HTML Source
Set oXH = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
With oXH
    .Open "get", strURL, False
    .send
    x = .responseText
End With
Set oXH = Nothing
'Parse HTML Source for Title
If InStr(1, UCase(x), "<TITLE>") Then
    stPnt = InStr(1, UCase(x), "<TITLE>") + Len("<TITLE>")
    fgetMetaTitle = Mid(x, stPnt, InStr(stPnt, UCase(x), "</TITLE>") - stPnt)
    'This will handle the apostrophe:
    fgetMetaTitle = Replace(fgetMetaTitle, "&#039;", "'")
    'This will handle the dash:
    fgetMetaTitle = Replace(fgetMetaTitle, "&#8211;", "-")
Else
    fgetMetaTitle = ""
End If

End Function
```

Also check this: [HTML Entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)